# list populate by append function can't be sorted by sort function

Tags: python, list, sorting

I create a list with a loop using append function to populate the list.
and after I want to sort it with the list sort function on one of the element's attribute. but it doesn't work, can you guys help me, thank a lot.
here is the code

```
def processRawUrlData():
    rawData = readHtml()
    taskList = []
    for item in rawData:
        if item != '':
            taskList.append(processTask(item))
    taskList.sort(key=attrgetter('est_time'))
    for item in taskList:
        print(item.taskname)
        print(item.est_time)
        print(item.submittedDate)
    return taskList
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Do you get an exception? Does your list not get sorted at all, or does it get sorted, but not the way you intend? We can't guess these things! You may also want to show what the `est_time` attribute of the `processTask` return value looks like, since that's what you're trying to sort by.

Comment: please give a [mcve]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: when I say it doesn't work, it means that the list doesn't get sorted at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have to be more specific and provide a comparison function so that your list can be sorted. Took the code below from the following site. Hope it helps:

https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

```
    >>> student_tuples = [
            ('john', 'A', 15),
            ('jane', 'B', 12),
            ('dave', 'B', 10),
    ]
    >>> sorted(student_tuples, key=lambda student: student[2])   # sort by age
    [('dave', 'B', 10), ('jane', 'B', 12), ('john', 'A', 15)]
```